# Peirush HaMishnah L'Rambam

Tags: rambam, internet, talmud-gemara

Anyone know where I can find Rambam's commentary on Mishnah online?  I am especially looking for his commentary to Avos.

Answer (score 5):

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37946&st=&pgnum=296